# When using JQuery for AJAX, why is my python file not returning an alert upon success

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

I have done my best to follow all the different Python/JQuery/AJAX threads, but I am fairly new to programming and could use some more help specific to my problem.  I am using Google App Engine, WebApp2 framework and Twitter Bootstrap for formatting to create a customer entry form.  The HTML template I have created functions as expected, but I am currently trying to connect the HTML frontend to the high replication datastore backend and am experiencing difficulties.

I would like to use asynchronous methodologies to save my form once it has been populated.  When the user presses the save button, it currently triggers the following

```
creates.js
    function createCustomer()
{
    var clientNumber = document.getElementById("clientNumber").value;
    var clientCreateDate = document.getElementById("clientCreateDate").value;
    var clientName = document.getElementById("clientName").value;
    var clientAddress1 = document.getElementById("clientAddress1").value;
    var clientAddress2 = document.getElementById("clientAddress2").value;
    var clientState = document.getElementById("clientState").value;
    var clientZip = document.getElementById("clientZip").value;
    var clientPhone = document.getElementById("clientPhone").value;
    var clientFax = document.getElementById("clientFax").value;
    var clientWebsite = document.getElementById("clientWebsite").value;
    var clientEmail = document.getElementById("clientEmail").value;
    var clientNotes = document.getElementById("clientNotes").value;
    var clientFinancing = document.getElementById("clientFinancing").value;
    var clientStatus = document.getElementById("clientStatus").value;

    $.ajax({    
    url: "/json/customerDBBridge.py",
    type: "post",
    data: {'clientNumber':clientNumber, 'clientCreateDate':clientCreateDate, 'clientName':clientName, 'clientAddress1':clientAddress1, 
            'clientAddress2':clientAddress2, 'clientState':clientState, 'clientZip':clientZip, 'clientPhone':clientPhone, 'clientFax':clientFax,
            'clientWebsite':clientWebsite, 'clientEmail':clientEmail, 'clientNotes':clientNotes, 'clientFinancing':clientFinancing, 'clientStatus':clientStatus},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
    });
```

This then calls the customerDBBridge.py file:
    #!/usr/bin/python

```
import json
import sys
import webapp2
import cgi
import ClientDB 

result = {'success':'true','message':'The Command Completed Successfully'};

#myobject = json.load(string_received)

#my_client = clientDB(clientNumber=myobject.clientNumber, clientCreateDate=myobject.clientCreateDate, clientName=myobject.clientName, clientAddress1=myobject.clientAddress1,
#clientAddress2=myobject.clientAddress2, clientState=myobject.clientState, clientZip=myobject.clientZip, clientPhone=myobject.clientPhone, clientFax=myobject.clientFax,
#clientWebsite=myobject.clientWebsite, clientEmail=myobject.clientEmail, clientNotes=myobject.clientNotes, clientFinancing=myobject.clientFinancing, clientStatus=myobject.clientStatus)

return json.dumps(result)
```

When looking in firebug, there are no errors when the button is pressed and the JSON object is being passed to the clientDBBridge.py file, but I am unable to get the result alert back as expected.  I need to to know whether my code that is currently commented out is firing.

Comment: Please add an `error` handler function also to your `ajax`, after your `success` function. You'll get an error there if at all any.

Comment: That Python file will give a SyntaxEerror as you have a return outside a function. Is that really your entire code?

Comment: What web framework are you using?  The url "/json/customerDBBridge.py" looks suspicious - especially if you are using App Engine.  You can add some logging to the server script to verify it is even being called.

Comment: @surajck The error handler helped me see that I had a 500 server error.  Turns our I had a handler set up wrong in my main file.  I was calling return rather than system.out.write and that made all the difference.  Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Roseman No, that was not all.  You were correct that the error was actually outside of the code.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff Deskins Thanks Jeff.  Part of the problem was also that I was calling /json/customerDBBridge.py rather than having a handler take care of it in my main.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!